# Output of generating new string array does n't come as expected

Tags: java, arrays

> You have been two ints, n1 and n2 as input. Return a new String[] containing the numbers from n1 to n2 as strings, except for multiples of 3, use "Fizz" instead of the number, for multiples of 5 use "Buzz", and for multiples of both 3 and 5 use "FizzBuzz

## Sample Input #1

generate(2,8)

## Sample Output #1

{"2","Fizz","4","Buzz","Fizz","7","8"}

## Sample Input #2

generate(10,16)

## Sample Output #2

{"Buzz","11","Fizz","13","14","FizzBuzz",16}

**MyApproach**

I am checking from n1 to n2 wether the nos are divisible by 3 & 5,by 3, and by 5.If it is divisible by 3 I am storing that string in strnew,divisible by 5 store that string in strnew else store that string in strnew,

```
public String[] generate(int start, int stop)
 {
   String strnew[]=new String[stop-start+1];
    
   {
    for(int i=start;i<=stop;i++)
     
    {
     
      if((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0))
      strnew[i]="FizzBuzz";
      else if(i%3==0)
      strnew[i]="Fizz";
      else if(i%5==0)
      strnew[i]="Buzz";
      else
      strnew[i]=""+i;
    } 

    return strnew;
  }
 
 }
```

MyQuestion:

What I am doing wrong?Can anyone guide me.

Output

```
Parameters  Actual Output   Expected Output

'2' '8'     null            {'2','Fizz','4','Buzz','Fizz','7','8'}
```

Comment: Where is the stack trace

Comment: Also, stop and start might be null...

Comment: first things first. The first cell of your array is [0], not [start]. On an unrelated note, technically 2 and 8 are called arguments. Parameters don't have an actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to offset your position in your storage array (`start` isn't `0`). There's no need for a block after `strnew` and I would prefer braces on the `if` and `else if` blocks. Something like,

```
static String[] generate(int start, int stop) {
    String strnew[] = new String[stop - start + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < strnew.length; i++) {
        int value = start + i;
        if (value % 15 == 0) {
            strnew[i] = "FizzBuzz";
        } else if (value % 3 == 0) {
            strnew[i] = "Fizz";
        } else if (value % 5 == 0) {
            strnew[i] = "Buzz";
        } else {
            strnew[i] = String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }
    return strnew;
}
```

Comment: Frisch Your code is great.+1 for that .But it created one more doubt that why I need to address all arrays with index=0.

Comment: Arrays are of fixed length in Java, and the first index (in an array) is `0`.

Comment: Why First index is 0?Why can't I start with 1,2,3...etc

Comment: [JLS-10.4. Array Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4) says (in part) *All arrays are `0`-origin. An array with length `n` can be indexed by the integers `0` to `n-1`.*

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] generate(int start, int stop){
    String ar[]=new String[stop-start+1];
    int num=start;
    String s1="Fizz";
    String s2="Buzz";
    String s3="FizzBuzz";
    for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
        if((num%3==0)&&(num%5!=0)){
            ar[i]=s1;
        }
       else if((num%5==0)&&(num%3!=0)){
            ar[i]=s2;
        }
        else if((num%3==0)&&(num%5==0)){
            ar[i]=s3;
        }
        else{
            String str="";
            str=str+num;
            ar[i]=str;
        }
        num=num+1;
    }

    return ar;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.